# real world example of Abstract Factory Design Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-pattern, abstract-factory

I am writing this question after reading many posts on Abstract Factory Design Pattern in C#.I really cannot make a real world use case sense out of the examples that all those posts provide. All I could see was some basic example of cars/computers/phones etc.I understand that they are important to provide a simple explanation. But I am really unable to map it to anything real world, because if I would really follow such examples, my code would be changing every other week when I would want to bring new objects.

The below is the sample code for it

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{

    public interface AbstractProductA { }
    public class ProductA1 : AbstractProductA { }
    public class ProductA2 : AbstractProductA { }


    public interface AbstractProductB { }
    public class ProductB1 : AbstractProductB { }
    public class ProductB2 : AbstractProductB { }


    public interface AbstractFactory
    {
        AbstractProductA CreateProductA();
        AbstractProductB CreateProductB();
    }


    public class ConcreteFactoryA : AbstractFactory
    {
        public AbstractProductA CreateProductA()
        {
            return new ProductA1();
        }

        public AbstractProductB CreateProductB()
        {
            return new ProductB1();
        }
    }

    public class ConcreteFactoryB : AbstractFactory
    {
        public AbstractProductA CreateProductA()
        {
            return new ProductA2();
        }

        public AbstractProductB CreateProductB()
        {
            return new ProductB2();
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        private AbstractProductA _productA;
        private AbstractProductB _productB;

        public Client(AbstractFactory factory)
        {
            _productA = factory.CreateProductA();
            _productB = factory.CreateProductB();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, how to make sense out of it. I can understand how it is working, but it looks so naive. One thing is that maybe the kind of example everybody on tutorial sites are choosing is not the right one.

Also, what benefit is it really giving me. I can do it in the usual non abstract factory kind of way using interfaces and the entire thing would still work just fine (design wise).

Detailed explanation with example is what I am looking for

Comment: .NET Data providers is the example of AbstractFactory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z47aJGe7jR4

Comment: IMHO, abstract factory is overrated. It has very little benefit over using gerenics.

Answer (score 8):

Here I demonstrate to you the following simple example based on what I used to implement in my project a long time ago.

```
public interface IBluetoothCommFactory { }

public interface IWifiCommFactory { }

/// <summary>
/// This is our base factory
/// </summary>
public interface ICommunicationBaseFactory
{
    IBluetoothCommFactory InitializeBluetoothCommunication();
    IWifiCommFactory InitializeWiFiCommnucation();
}

public class BluetoothCommunication : IBluetoothCommFactory
{
    public BluetoothCommunication()
    {
        // Implement some init logic here...
        Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth Communication was initialized");
     }
}

public class WiFiCommunication : IWifiCommFactory
{
    public WiFiCommunication()
    {
        // Implement some init logic here...
        Console.WriteLine("WIFI (generic) Communication was initialized");
    }
}
```

Above are the basic implementations of a "generic" *BluetoothCommunication* and a "generic" *WiFiCommunication*. Let's say we want to make a product called *ProductPrototypeONE* which uses those generic communication types.

```
public class ProductPrototypeONE : ICommunicationBaseFactory
{
    public IBluetoothCommFactory InitializeBluetoothCommunication()
    {
        return new BluetoothCommunication();
    }

    public IWifiCommFactory InitializeWiFiCommnucation()
    {
        return new WiFiCommunication();
    }
}
```

Then in our client code:

```
ICommunicationBaseFactory baseFactory = new ProductPrototypeONE();
baseFactory.InitializeBluetoothCommunication();
baseFactory.InitializeWiFiCommnucation();

/* CONSOLE OUTPUT */  
Bluetooth Communication was initialized
WIFI (generic) Communication was initialized
```

Next, we want to add another requirement to create a product which has Bluetooth Low Energy type and some specific WiFi types. Then, with the same factory we created, we can continue implement these:

```
public class BluetoothLowEnergyCommunication : IBluetoothCommFactory
{
    public BluetoothLowEnergyCommunication()
    {
        // Implement some init logic here...
        Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth Low Energy Communication was initialized");
    }
}

public class WiFiLowBandCommunication : IWifiCommFactory
{
    public WiFiLowBandCommunication()
    {
        // Implement some init logic here...
        Console.WriteLine("WIFI Low Band Communication was initialized");
    }
}

public class WifiHighBandCommunication : IWifiCommFactory
{
    public WifiHighBandCommunication()
    {
        // Implement some init logic here...
        Console.WriteLine("WIFI High Band Communication was initialized");
    }
}
```

Then we created ProductPrototypeTWO as a concrete class:

```
public enum BluetoothType
{
    CLASSIC_TYPE,
    BLE_TYPE
}

public enum WiFiType
{
    LOW_BAND,
    HIGH_BAND
}

public class ProductPrototypeTWO : ICommunicationBaseFactory
{
    private BluetoothType _bluetoothType;
    private WiFiType _wifiType;

    public ProductPrototypeTWO(BluetoothType bluetoothType, WiFiType wifiType)
    {
        _bluetoothType = bluetoothType;
        _wifiType = wifiType;
    }

    public IBluetoothCommFactory InitializeBluetoothCommunication()
    {
        switch (_bluetoothType)
        {
            case BluetoothType.CLASSIC_TYPE:
                return new BluetoothCommunication();
            case BluetoothType.BLE_TYPE:
                return new BluetoothLowEnergyCommunication();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown Bluetooth type");
        }
    }

    public IWifiCommFactory InitializeWiFiCommnucation()
    {
        switch (_wifiType)
        {
            case WiFiType.LOW_BAND:
                return new WiFiLowBandCommunication();
            case WiFiType.HIGH_BAND:
                return new WifiHighBandCommunication();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown WIFI type");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, client code:

```
ICommunicationBaseFactory baseFactory = new ProductPrototypeONE();
baseFactory.InitializeBluetoothCommunication();
baseFactory.InitializeWiFiCommnucation();

baseFactory = new ProductPrototypeTWO(BluetoothType.BLE_TYPE, WiFiType.HIGH_BAND);
baseFactory.InitializeBluetoothCommunication();
baseFactory.InitializeWiFiCommnucation();
```

This is what you have in the output:

```
Bluetooth Communication was initialized
WIFI (generic) Communication was initialized
Bluetooth Low Energy Communication was initialized
WIFI High Band Communication was initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading a lot of articles and learning new things every time I try to get my head around it what I understand(and hopefully am right) is that
**Abstract Factory add a layer of abstraction over Factory pattern**. Thus I will give you a very small and quick example.

Say you have a set of object creation methods in Factory and this should be different across different clients, then we use abstract factory. Hence what abstract factory does is create a family according to the type you have.

Hope this was what you were looking for and people who come across this question is checking for and hope that what I have jotted down over here makes sense.

Comment: Found this good read. https://endjin.com/blog/2019/05/design-patterns-in-c-factory-method-and-abstract-factory